# Scope ruby comentarios peor valorados

Tags: ruby, método, scope

soy una neófita en esto de Ruby, y para una aplicación que estoy haciendo, necesito definir un método y un scope para que me muestre los comentarios peor valorados en orden ascendente: primero el peor y luego va mejorando.

He escrito el inverso, gracias a unas pautas de un ejercicio, sin embargo no soy capaz de hacer el de los peores comentarios. 
Hasta ahora tengo este scope en mi model comment.rb:

```
scope :rating_desc, -> { order(rating: :desc) }
```

Este método en my model user.rb:

```
def highest_rating_comment
  comments.rating_desc.first
end
```

Y en mi show products view esto:

```
<%= @product.highest_rating_comment %>
```

Cómo habría de hacer para que me devolviera los peores resultados?
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Para los peores resultados utiliza `:asc` en lugar de `:desc`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que había estado haciendo, y no funcionaba, pero porque había definido el método fuera de la clase 'user' en user.rb...

En fin, ya está solucionado, muchas gracias de nuevo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías definir otro scope para orden ascendente:

```
scope :rating_asc, -> { order(rating: :asc) }
```

y llamarlo en otra funcion

```
def worst_rating_comment
  comments.rating_asc.first
end
```